# AG-Grid (Vanilla JS): Loader overlay does not display when duplicating rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ag-grid

I am using AG-Grid without a framework to create an Excel-like editable table. I have implemented the ability to select one or more rows and have them duplicated immediately under the original row.

You may find a [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/fe3C4DYOJKaGNmjh3Lgq).

The issue arises with attempting to call the Loading Overlay on scripts.js:421 and hide in on scripts.js:438.

```
gridOptions.api.showLoadingOverlay();
...
gridOptions.api.hideOverlay();
```

If you attempt to duplicate the rows, the provided overlay does not show. If you view the console, you can see that the div.ag-bl-overlay is manipulated but the loading overlay never shows.

I have also attempted to manually force an overlay onto the grid using any outside function. This too does not display.

How do I get the loadingOverlay to display while I am inside the 'duplicateRows()' function?

Comment: Did you debug your code and did you use the F12 tools to check whether there are any errors?

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes I did. On both my local development server and the Plunker, no warnings or errors are produced in the console.

Comment: There seems to be something inherent in `insertItemsAtIndex` that is hiding the overlay, perhaps change your logic so as to not use this function

Comment: @JarodMoser Thanks. I might try that. But with further work on my project, I'm finding that the api loading overlay doesn't seem to want to show itself during most (if not all) API operations (for example, `gridOptions.api.setColumnState();`. I believe I will try to seek out a way to do a loading overlay not controlled by ag-grid directly.